# Cost effective sagging palm trees

Tags: design

I'd like to build about a dozen palm trees that have some curve or sag to them, not just vertical.
The 2 methods I've found are

1. The Baryonyx face-off set uses a [dinosaur tail](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40378#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) to make a curve in the tree.  Instructions can be found [here](https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/75935/Baryonyx_Face-Off:_The_Treasure_Hunt), starting at about step 33.
2. The various [Palm trunk pieces](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=palm%20trunk#T=A) available on Bricklink.

Unfortunately, both of these pieces are hard to find in quantity and can be priced quite high.  Is there a more cost effective way to build sagging palm trees?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could loosely stack [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b&name=Brick,%20Round%201%20x%201%20Open%20Stud&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C) around a core [Hose, Rigid 3mm D.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=528). As long as the stack is loose, you should be able to bend the trunk to your desired shape.

As a bonus, you get the segmented look of the trunk for free. A reference photo:

[image]

Or if your scale is smaller, maybe consider [Hose, Ribbed 7mm D.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=522).

[image]

Comment: That seems to work. I'm having  a hard time getting the rigid hose through the 1x1 round bricks sometimes. Are there any particular techniques for threading it through ?

Comment: I've had trouble when the hose has been damaged (kinked, deformed, etc), but the diameter of the hole in the brick should fit an undamaged hose just fine. If you can, start from the top of the brick so you're not trying to line up the hole blind, and be sure you're gripping the hose close to the brick so it flexes the least amount possible. Maybe others have better tips.

Comment: If you're not strict about it being 100% LEGO parts, you could just use any old piece of string, thread, or wire instead.